# Missing overviews for mosaic dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, mosaic-dataset

I have a mosaic dataset with rasters that cover the entire US - One for each county.  When I generate the overviews, there is a chunk missing.  When you zoom in, the imagery shows up.  There are no errors or warnings from the analysis tool and there were no errors or warnings from the generate overviews tool.  I expect that there may be a single raster that could be causing problems and preventing the overview image from generating.  Does anybody have any troubleshooting ideas for me?

I'm using ArcGIS for Desktop Standard version 10.3.  Below is a screenshot of the mosaic dataset as it is displayed in ArcMap.  The green lines are the footprints of each individual raster.  The rasters are .sid files.

[image: This is what it looks like with the missing overview panel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add the missing rasters to a new mosaic dataset (Mosaic_01) and then put the old rasters to anther mosaic data set (Mosaic_02)( except the raster that you already added in mosaic_01) , now build the overviews for both mosaics. finally but (Mosaic_01 and Mosaic_02) in a new mosaic (MasterMosaic_01_02) and build the over views for it.

Comment: I'll give that a try.  Can you explain why that would make a difference?  Is a dataset of datasets optimal?

Comment: Actually I don’t know, but I have faced this issue before and I have solve it using this walk around, I have test it and it works fine with me, I feel that the mosaic datasets do not have a stable behavior in ArcGIS, I have faced many issue with them and every issue with a new walk around. Sorry for this inconvenient

Comment: That worked.  I don't know why and I wish I did but thanks.